# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(3^nx)}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

For what values of $x$ does $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(3^nx)}{2^n}$$ converge?

I tried as follows:
Since $\frac{\cos (3^nx)}{2^n} \le \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n$, therefore $\sum \frac{\cos (3^nx)}{2^n} \le \sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ and since RHS  is a G.P which converges, the required series converges irrespective of what $x$ is.
Therefore the sum converges for all $x$.

Is this way right?

Comment: You need to show that the sequence is also bounded below and convergent. In particular, you could show absolute convergence of the series.

Comment: What to do u want say?

Comment: Here you should show that the sum cannot oscillate and lot more technical problems will follow so instead show it is absolutely convergent

Comment: The idea is ok. Just put absolute values there: $|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^n x)}{2^n}|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{\cos(3^n x)}{2^n}|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=1$.

Comment: @JankoBracic it is better *not* to write all thos sums to infinite, for the first absolute value, in principle, does not mean anything until you prove the series converges...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think that everything cannot be proved here. One has to assume something. I guess that the question was if the above reasoning was ok. Of course, I could use some test for the convergence and related things why it is ok if I move the absolute value inside the sum... But that wouldn't actually answer the question. It would just show how smart I am ;)

Comment: Well, you cannot assume rhat the series converges, for that is precisely what you are trying to prove! You have instead to prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{\cos(3^n x)}{2^n}|$ converges as you did, and then quote the result that a series which converges absolutely converges. The first inequality you wrote is simply wrong unless you know in some other way that the first series converges.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct in case the variable x is always real
 In case of complex variables this might not be true.
However if this is a hw question dont write the answer in this form if your teacher/professor do not expect such an answer.

Comment: how can we check if this function is continuous?